# Reading a line and removing Spaces from matrix in a file

Tags: c

OK so I manage to write to the file `char` by `char` but it writes twice the numbers and it it still write it with spaces. Any advice and solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

extern int errno;
#define MAX_LEN 18

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd[2], des, bytes, target;
    char buffer[161];
    int fdr, fdw;   // file descriptors
    char c;

    fdr = open(argv[1],  O_RDONLY);   // open files
    fdw = open("gg.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fdr < 0 || fdw < 0) {
        perror("failed to open input or output files");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (read(fdr, &c, 1)) { // read/write a single char from/to the files
        if (c != ' ' && c != EOF) {
            if (write(fdw, &c, 1) != 1) {
                perror("write() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }    // echo char to stdout
    }

    close(fdr);   // close the files
    close(fdw);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

EDIT SECTION

hey again,

i managed to read the file and write it to new one without spaces but i'm trying to insert the values to matrix but im getting an error trying to open the new file.

i have changed the permissions

```
fdw = open("gg.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

the function

```
void removeSpaces(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE],int fdr, int fdw) {

    char c;
    char matBuffer={0};
    while (read(fdr, &c, 1))          // read/write a single char
    {                                  // from/to the files
        if (c != ' ') {
            if (write(fdw, &c, 1) != 1) {
                perror("write() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;
    while(read(fdw, &matBuffer, 1))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=matBuffer-'0';
                        k++;
                    }
            k=0;
        }

    }

}
```

The whole program

```
// C program to illustrate
// open system call
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAX_LEN 18
#define SIZE 9
void removeSpaces(int matrix[SIZE][SIZE],int fdr, int fdw) {

    char c;
    char matBuffer={0};
    while (read(fdr, &c, 1))          // read/write a single char
    {                                  // from/to the files
        if (c != ' ') {
            if (write(fdw, &c, 1) != 1) {
                perror("write() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;
    while(read(fdw, &matBuffer, 1))
    {
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i][j]=matBuffer-'0';
                        k++;
                    }
            k=0;
        }

    }

}
int is_safe(int matrix[9][9],int n, int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;
    //checking in row
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        //there is a cell with same value
        if(matrix[r][i] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    //checking column
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        //there is a cell with the value equal to i
        if(matrix[i][c] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    //checking sub matrix
    int row_start = (r/3)*3;
    int col_start = (c/3)*3;
    for(i=row_start;i<row_start+3;i++)
    {
        for(j=col_start;j<col_start+3;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]==n)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int pipe_descs[2];
    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    int fdr, fdw;   // file descriptors
    int i,j;
/*  if (pipe(pipe_descs) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_t status = fork();
    if(status ==0 )
    {

    }*/
    fdr = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);   // open files
    fdw = open("gg.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fdr < 0 || fdw < 0) { //validation for error
        perror("failed to open input or output files");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    removeSpaces(matrix,fdr, fdw);
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){    /* Iterate of each row */
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){    /* In each row, go over each col element  */
          printf("%c ",matrix[i][j]); /* Print each row element */
        }
        printf("\n");        /* Finish a row, start a new line */
      }
    close(fdr);   // close the files
    close(fdw);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Read up on what strlen() does.

Comment: From `man bzero`: *CONFORMING TO         top

The bzero() function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001); use memset(3) in new programs. POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of bzero(). The bzero() function first appeared in 4.3BSD.*

Comment: This code has a mismatch in braces. Fix it until it compiles at least, and then we can have a look at your problem. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` can be helpful.

Comment: buffer[161] is out-of-bounds.

Comment: If you don't use `argc` and `argv` you can just use `int main(void)`

Comment: ..and, anyway, you loaded the required offset into 'bytes' on the line above and then.......just forgot/ignored it:(

Comment: Why would you `fork` just to do this? Show us a minimal complete code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: i just edited the code

Comment: Don't redeclare `errno` manually.

Comment: Your second call to `open` is missing the mode argument (required for `O_CREAT`).

Comment: `while (read(fdr, &c, 1))` is wrong. `read` returns non-zero on error.

Comment: `c != EOF` makes no sense. `c` is a `char`; `EOF` is not. Either this will never be true, or it will treat a valid character as EOF by mistake.

Comment: `buffer` is unused.

Comment: @dinushki: please do not correct the code in the question as it makes the comments, discussion and answers inconsistent. You can add **EDIT** sections at the end of the question for further information or trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not test for `read` errors, `read` can return `-1` for error, which would not stop the `while` loop.
- testing `c != EOF` is meaningless. `EOF` is returned by `getc()` to indicate end of stream or input error, `read` indicates these conditions in its return value, `c` is always a byte value if `read` succeeded and returned `1`.
- `gg.txt` is not truncated by `open` with the given flags. Chances are you are overwriting the beginning of the file and for some reason the file is longer from previous attempts and still contains previously written data. You must also pass the mode bits for the file creation as the third argument to `open`. Use this:

  ```
  // open the file for writing, truncate if it exists or create with
  // read/write permission for user, read permission for group and others
  fdw = open("gg.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
  ```
- the comment `// echo char to stdout` does not seem to refer to any code.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fdr, fdw;   // file descriptors
    char c;

    fdr = open(argv[1],  O_RDONLY);   // open files
    if (fdr < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open input file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // open the output file for writing, truncate if it exists or create with
    // read/write permission for user, read permission for group and others
    fdw = open("gg.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fdw < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open output file %s: %s\n", "gg.txt", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read/write a single char from/to the files
    while (read(fdr, &c, 1) == 1) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            if (write(fdw, &c, 1) != 1) {
                perror("write() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
    close(fdr);   // close the files
    close(fdw);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code again .i'm getting this error of the writing "write() failed: Success
"

Comment: the -1 was the problem.but hey,can you explain the 0666?

Comment: `0666`, which should really be `0644` is the permission mask documented in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: for some reason when im trying to open the file it takes a minute and it seems like it write empty char or something.the size is approx 300 MB now

Comment: @dinushki:  I posted a corrected version. Verify that you test for read success correctly:` while (read(fdr, &c, 1) == 1)` If you test `!= -1`, you will have an endless loop writing the last byte again repeatedly at the end of `gg.txt`.